# Nested Comments with nested answers: undefined method `answers' for nil:NilClass | Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement nested answers into comments, which are nested into auctions.

There is a auctions.rb model, which:

```
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :answers, :through => :comments
```

a comments.rb model, which:

```
belongs_to :auction
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
```

a answers.rb model, which:

```
belongs_to :comment
```

the answers_controller inherits from the comments_controller:

```
class AnswersController < CommentsController
  before_action :all_answers, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_answer, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :js

  # New Answer (Form)
  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
    @comments.answers.build
  end

  # Create Answer
  def create
    @answer = @comment.answers.build(answer_params)
    @answer.user_id = current_user.id
    @answer.save
  end

  # Edit Answer
  def update
    @answer.update!(answer_params)
  end

  # Delete Answer
  def destroy
    @answer = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @answer.comment
    @answer.destroy
  end

  private

  def all_answers
    @answers = @comment.answers.all
  end

  def set_answer
    @answer = @comment.answers.find(params[:id])
  end

  def answer_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

The Error:

> NoMethodError in Auctions#show app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
>   where line #20 raised: undefined method `answers' for nil:NilClass

```
     <div class="col s12" id="answer-form" style="display:none;"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col s12" id="answers"><%= render @comment.answers %></div>
   </div>
```

With <%= render @comment.answers %> I want to display all existing answers below the related comment. What am I doing wrong?

**auction_controller**

```
class AuctionsController < ApplicationController
  # Index of all auctions
  def index
    @auctions = Auction.all
  end

  # Show Auction by :id
  def show
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    # Find Seller by ID
    @seller = User.find(@auction.user_id)
    # Find highest bid, by finding all related bids and ordering in descending and picking the first
    @highest_bid = Bid.where(auction_id: params[:id]).order("amount DESC").first
    # Find product
    @product = Product.find(@auction.product_id)
  end

  # New Auction Form
  def new
    @auction = Auction.new
  end

  # Edit Auction
  def edit
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Create new Auction
  def create
    # Create new Auction
    @auction = Auction.new(auction_params)
    # Save Id of User (Seller)
    @auction.user_id = current_user.id
    # If auction was created successfully
    if @auction.save
      # display the created auction
      redirect_to @auction, :notice => "Auction created"
    else
      # display Form again if unsuccessful
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  # Update existing Auction
  def update
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    # Validation
    if @auction.update(auction_params)
      redirect_to @auction, :notice => "Auction updated"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  # Delete Auction
  def destroy
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    @auction.destroy

    redirect_to auctions_path, :notice => "Auction deleted"
  end

  private
  # set required parameters for new created Auctions
  def auction_params
    params.require(:auction).permit(:condition, :product_name)
  end
end
```

comments_controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_auction
  before_action :all_comments, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_comment, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  respond_to :html, :js

  # New Comment (Form)
  def new
    @comment = Comment.new
    @auction.comments.build
  end

  # Create Comment
  def create
    @comment = @auction.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.save
  end

  # Edit Comment
  def update
    @comment.update!(comment_params)
  end

  # Delete Comment
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @auction = @comment.auction
    @comment.destroy
  end

  private
  def set_auction
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
  end

  def all_comments
    @comments = @auction.comments.all
  end

  def set_comment
    @comment = @auction.comments.find(params[:id])
  end

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

Normal Comments work. Only Comment Answers don't work.

Comment: What is the action where the error is raised? new? index? etc?

Comment: The action is: Auctions#show, can we see your Auction controller? Looks like @comment is not define.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti - the error is raised in the show action of the auction.

Comment: @charly-m - I have added the auction controller and also the comments controller. There shouldn't be a problem with the def of comment (only answers are not working)

Comment: I think you forget to define @comment in your Auction#show , or you're not using the right route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error happens in `Auctions#show`, the error clearly tells you that you are trying to call `answers` on a nil object. Therefore, it means `@comment` is nil in that view.

In fact, if you check the `show` action, you never fetch/assign any object to `@comment`.

```
  # Show Auction by :id
  def show
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    # Find Seller by ID
    @seller = User.find(@auction.user_id)
    # Find highest bid, by finding all related bids and ordering in descending and picking the first
    @highest_bid = Bid.where(auction_id: params[:id]).order("amount DESC").first
    # Find product
    @product = Product.find(@auction.product_id)
  end
```

In order to fix it, make sure `@comment` is properly assigned to a `Comment` instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's another problem here:

```
  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
    @comments.answers.build
  end
```

You haven't got a variable called `@comments`, hence your form can't actually build answers off it. In fact, you're calling `@comment` in two other methods, where I can't even see it being declared:

```
  def all_answers
    @answers = @comment.answers.all
  end

  def set_answer
    @answer = @comment.answers.find(params[:id])
  end
```

---

The only time you've declared `@comment`is in the `destroy`method:

```
  def destroy
    @answer = Comment.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @answer.comment
    @answer.destroy
  end
```

Even then, it's weird.

Why are you calling the `Comment` model with the `@answer` variable? Surely you'd have an `Answer` model with `comments` attached by way of a `has_many` relationship?

I'd recommend you keeping it brain-dead simple:

```
#app/models/answer.rb
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end

#app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :answer
end
```

This means when you call your actions controller, you'll be able to apply the following:

```
def show
   @answer = Answer.find params[:id]
   @comment = @answer.comments.build
end
```

If you wanted to have comments act as answers, you need to keep the models separate. Use a hierchy gem, like [`closure tree`](https://github.com/mceachen/closure_tree). This way, you'll be able to keep your Answers/Comments in hierarchy order, whilst keeping the Models consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to mention, that I started learning rails 2 weeks ago. First I only had the auction and comment model. Normal comments are working fine (a comment is like a question btw). Then I thought, that it would be easy to just implement the answers into the comments (like i implemented comments into auctions). Therefore I did the routes like this:   `resources :auctions do
    resources :comments do
      resources :answers
    end
  end`

Is the solution I am trying to do completely impossible?

Comment: Nice! Did you have any previous programming experience? Seems quite complicated to attempt within 2 weeks of beginning to learn!

Comment: I just know html, css, a little bit of js, java and cake/php. Until now I focused more on frontend. But since I realised whats possible if I I could do the backend development, I immediately started learning Ruby basics and Rails. Yes, its very complicated for me, but I think that the best way to learn something is by doing it and learning from failures.

Comment: Yes, you're totally right :) Keep going, you've got the right idea. Your past programming experience will also help you a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :)